# punycode is deprecated in npm - what should I replace it with?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, yarnpkg, punycode

I'm using the npm module `punycode` in my Angular project.
VsCode tells me it's deprecated and https://nodejs.org/api/punycode.html#punycode_punycode
confirms:

> The version of the punycode module bundled in Node.js is being deprecated. In a future major version of Node.js this module will be removed. Users currently depending on the punycode module should switch to using the userland-provided Punycode.js module instead.

The suggestion is to switch to the 'userland-provided' module.
What is that?

There is a link to https://github.com/mathiasbynens/punycode.js and I tried including that in my package.json instad of 'punycode' and I get the same error.

Comment: Did you import the module as instructed in the readme: `const punycode = require('punycode/');`?

Comment: I think that is for node.js, as it's Angulare we're just using the es6 imports, not the commonJs node ones

Comment: It is just to change from where it is resolved. You have to force the import to come from local (node_modules etc.) rather than from node.js libraries. Try `import punycode from "punycode/";` for example.

Comment: I have done this, and changed the usages for (for example) toUnicode to punycode.toUnicode() which does "suppress" the deprecation error, but I'm not sure as there is no type knowledge (toUnicode is 'any'), so I will need to check this further and see. Thanks though.

Comment: "punycode is deprecated in npm" -- nitpick: punycode is deprecated in node, not in npm

Answer (score 30):

Recently I faced this same issue.

I highly recommend you use the LTS(long term support) version of the node.

You can validate the version here: https://nodejs.org/en

when I'm writing this answer the node LTS version is 20.10.0

so then in your command line you should perform:

```
$nvm install 20.10.0
$nvm use 20.10.0
```

This solves the problem, because makes you use the most tested and approved version.

If I use the version with latest features (actually 21.5.0) I will face the problem reported here. There is an issue open in github to solve it by the way.

You can see more details here: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/9005

Comment: "downgrade node" is not a future-proof solution. [yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/9009/commits/859d7398b753d22e0e74c3b07ba88c1a566691ae) and [pngwin](https://github.com/corigne/pngwin/commit/9995ebce9c2ce53f5899a6e6130635865743fecc) solve this by using [punycode from NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/punycode): `const punycode = require('punycode/');`

Comment: use always long term support version. my problem solved

Answer (score 4):

[Refer to this GitHub issue](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/1599)

In my case, despite not using punycode directly in my codebase, Nodemailer relies on it. To address this, I implemented a custom script, as detailed in the linked GitHub issue.

If your situation differs, you may need to identify which library is utilizing punycode and apply a similar workaround until an official fix is released. Feel free to share a test case publicly, and I'd be happy to assist you further.

Answer (score 1):

It is deprecated on node version 21.0.0.
Use version node version 18.

```bash
nvm use 18
```

Comment: I am using v20.11.1 node works fine for me on LTS version

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, this solution with ('punycode/') - does not work. It doesn't seem to have any problems with any LTS version, but on anything 21.^ and above - unfortunately not a single hack I've seen - does NOT work (so far). I tried the final LTS version (v20.11.0) this morning and it works.

Comment: I note you just tried to edit someone elses answer, please do not edit significant changes into someone elses answer. Either suggest the change in a comment, or add your own answer (as you have done)

Answer (score 1):

I also got the message:

> (node:14220) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.

I solved it by running `npm update ajv`.

AJV stands for Another JSON Schema Validator.

Answer (score 0):

Frequently, usage of the `punycode` module was simply for conversion of a domain name to ASCII, e.g., when MIME-encoding an address.

Yes, the module does a lot more, but commonly, you're just using the `toASCII()` function, handing it a domain name. For that, this deprecation, confusion over the magic trailing slash, further confusion when using ESM imports, all ends up being a bit complicated.

If that's the case, then the `domainToASCII()` function in the `node:url` package might be a simpler way to get your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm used Ubuntu and I have similar error.
Clearing cache don't solved my problem.
After remove nodejs and installation via nvm, problem has been solved

source: https://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-nvm-on-ubuntu-22-04/

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35732643)

Answer (score -2):

First:

```bash
npm install punycode --save
```

Second:

Then in `node_modules` go to the directory tr46 > index.js

```
// Replace this:
const punycode = require('punycode');
// With this:
const punycode = require('punycode/');
```

Comment: Is this a workaround or the suggested way of doing it?

Comment: Never edit anything in node_modules

Comment: You can edit things in `node_modules`, but be aware your edits will be gone next time you run `npm install`, unless you also save them via something like `patch-package`. However, editing a dependency directly is almost never the correct choice, unless you are stuck with something you can't update or isn't being maintained.

Comment: That's why "Never edit anything in node_modules" 