# punycode error while running backend server

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose, punycode

[INFO] 18:13:52 Restarting: C:\Code\MERN_Projects\podify_app\server\src\db\index.ts has been modified
(node:22692) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

I am expecting why this warning showing in terminal while i run server

Comment: Have a look at the comments in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68774489/) or [the relevant documenation.](https://nodejs.org/api/punycode.html#:~:text=The%20version%20of%20the%20punycode,this%20module%20will%20be%20removed.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can dowgrade your Node to the 20.9 version.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling Node.js from your machine depends on how you installed it. Here are the general steps for different methods:

If you installed Node.js via package manager:

For Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get remove npm
```

For macOS (if you used Homebrew):

```
brew uninstall node
```

If you installed Node.js via a binary package from nodejs.org:

For macOS:

You can remove the Node.js folder directly (default location is /usr/local/lib/node or /usr/local/lib/node_modules or /usr/local/include/node or /usr/local/bin/node). You can also check /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1.

For Windows:

You can uninstall it like any other Windows program. Go to the Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features, select Node.js, and click Uninstall.

If you installed Node.js via Node Version Manager (nvm):

You can uninstall a specific version with:

```
nvm uninstall <version>
```

To completely remove nvm, delete the nvm directory, which is typically located in your home directory (~/.nvm), and remove the lines that source nvm.sh in your shell profile (.bashrc, .bash_profile, .zshrc, etc.).

Remember to clear the npm cache after uninstalling Node.js:

```
npm cache clean -f
```

Also, check your system's PATH to make sure there are no references to Node.js or npm left.